# Número de parâmetros variáveis em C#

Tags: c#, .net

Eu sei que tem como fazer isso. Mas não estou conseguindo achar como.

Como faço para uma função aceitar um número variável de parâmetros do mesmo tipo, parecido como um array?

Assim eu posso chamar simplesmente assim:

```
UIMostra("Localização", "Informações Gerais", "Acessos")
```

ao invés de chamar criando um array (poluído):

```
UIMostra(new string[]{"Localização", "Informações Gerais", "Acessos"})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a palavra chave `params`, que permite indicar que um argumento array, irá receber uma lista de parâmetros sem necessitar passar um array explicitamente.

```
public void MeuMetodo(params object[] meusParametros)
{
    // usar o array de parametros
}
```

O argumento que recebe a palavra chave `params` deve ser o último, e deve ser declarado juntamente com um tipo de array.

Para passar uma lista de inteiros, por exemplo:

```
public void MetodoComListaDeInteiros(params int[] arrayInteiros)
{
    // faça algo com os inteiros... e.g. iterar eles num laço for, e mostrar na tela
    foreach (var eachNum in arrayInteiros)
        Console.WriteLine(eachNum);
}
```

e depois chame assim:

```
MetodoComListaDeInteiros(1, 2, 5, 10);
```

Todo método que aceita uma lista, também aceita um array, portanto o mesmo método acima também pode ser chamado assim:

```
MetodoComListaDeInteiros(new int[] { 1, 2, 5, 10 });
```

Answer (score 2):

É possível aprimorar um pouco o primeiro exemplo descrito pelo Miguel Angelo. Ao invés de utilizar variável do tipo *object*, é possível obter o mesmo resultado, porém com melhor aproveitamento de recursos com a utilização de *Generics*. Ficaria da seguinte forma:

**Declaração do método**

```
public void MeuMetodo<T>(params T[] meusParametros)
{
    foreach(T parametro in meusParametros)
        //restante do código
}
```

**Utilização:**

```
public class Cliente
{
    public Cliente(int id, String nome)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Nome = nome;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
}

Cliente cli1 = new Cliente(1, "João");
Cliente cli2 = new Cliente(2, "Maria");
Cliente cli3 = new Cliente(3, "José");

MeuMetodo<Cliente>(cli1, cli2, cli3);
```

Comment: +1 pelo uso de generics!